# How to sort columns in Excel so that only one value appears in each row?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, worksheet-function, sorting, spreadsheet

Say I have a a spreadsheet with the following data:

```
 A     B     C     D
---------------------
 2     1     0     2
 3     2     1     4
 5     3     3     6
 7     5     6     8
11     8    10    10
13    13    15    12
17    21    21    14
19    34    28    16
23    55    36    18
29    89    45    20
```

I want to sort the columns so that each row only contains a single value like this:

```
 A     B     C     D
---------------------
             0
       1     1
 2     2           2
 3     3     3
                   4
 5     5
             6     6
 7
       8           8
            10    10
11
                  12
13    13
                  14
            15
                  16
17
                  18
19
                  20
      21    21
23
            28
29
      34
            36
            45
      55
      89
```

Is there a quick way to do this in Excel?

Comment: Short answer, no.

Comment: None that is `built in` as far as I know. This looks as a Macro task to me. Pseudo code: Pick out all contents of a row, start repeat: select the lowest number from what was picked and reinsert it, move cursor down one row, if there is numbers remaining do insert an empty row, go back to 'repeat start' else end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your questions asks for a worksheet function, I don't think it's possible so I offer a macro (VBa) which should do what you want!

```
Option Explicit
Sub DoThis()

Dim row As Integer
row = 1

Dim col As Integer
col = 65

    Do While (Range("A" & row).Value <> "")

        Do While (Range(Chr(col) & row).Value <> "")

        Dim currentValue As Integer
        currentValue = Range(Chr(col) & row).Value

        Range(Chr(col + 7) & currentValue + 1).Value = currentValue

        col = col + 1
        Loop

        row = row + 1
        col = 65

    Loop        

End Sub
```

The Excel sheet I used (I only used the first 4 rows or your example due to time restraints)

[image]

And after I run it

[image]

As you can see, I've chosen to save the new table in a different place so it's non destructive.

Answer (score 0):

would resolve this with the Power Query Add-In. It takes a few steps to get there and a bit of coding in the Power Query language (M) to call the Table.Pivot function (it's not exposed in the Power Query UI).  But that's 1 line of code (the rest was built by clicking around in the Power Query UI), vs around 20 lines of VB code.

I've built a prototype which you can view or download - its "Power Query demo - Sort and spread rows by value.xlsx" in my One Drive:

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=4FA287BBC10EC562%21398

Basically my technique was to Unpivot the columns into rows, then copy the Value (representing each cell). Then I used the Table.Pivot function to return the data into the A,B,C,D columns.  Then I added a Group By and Sort using the "Copy of Value" column to achieve the final result.

The documentation for Table.Pivot is here:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/table-pivot-HA104111995.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA104122363

Another example of using Table.Pivot is here:

http://cwebbbi.wordpress.com/2013/11/25/pivoting-data-in-power-query/